# ReactJS deploy app error Cannot copy to clipboard: Command failed: xsel --clipboard --input

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a **ReactJS** app in my **Ubuntu 16.04** server but when I execute the command:

`serve -s build`

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot copy to clipboard: Command failed: xsel --clipboard --input
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device

   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                  │
   │   Serving!                                       │
   │                                                  │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000      │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://server_IP:5000   │
   │                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But the app is not loaded and is not accessible at the port `5000`.

How can I figured out this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding "-n" option to serve.

"-n, --no-clipboard                  Do not copy the local address to the clipboard"

Answer (score 2):

I avoided the problem by pointing the `nginx` server directly to the `/build` folder of my **ReactJS** project and specifically to the `index.html` file.

In this way I don't have the problem described in the question, because I don't execute anymore a service with `serve -s build` command.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- It's something todo with the clipboard module, try removing it from your APP with npm uninstall "Find the clipboard module name in package.json" then try to rebuild and see what happen?
- If the problem persists try to delete your node_modules and install again

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have any `clipboard` module in my `package.json` file...
I updated my question with my `package.json` file.