# serve -s build giving error of Can't open display: (null) : Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, aws-code-deploy, serve

I am trying to deploy my react application using aws code deploy but during execution of `serve -s build` it fails

The error is :

```
ERROR : Cannot copy to clipboard: Command failed: xsel --clipboard --input
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: Have you install npm packages?

Comment: yes, I did npm install successfully

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760655/reactjs-deploy-app-error-cannot-copy-to-clipboard-command-failed-xsel-clipbo